# Calculate chance of radius being smaller then X in a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, bivariate

If I have two variables X and Y that are both normally distributed with the same standard deviation σ and the same mean 0. They come together to form a circular bivariate normal distribution. How can I calculate the chance of a sample lying within a range r from the center (0,0)?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Did you try to write the integral in polar coordinates?

Comment: >Thanks! I have tired that, multiplying both normal distributions results in x²+y² in the exponent that can then be substituted for r² ans so on.  But trying to implement the result of this in R and getting nonsensical results which me me assume I was wrong. Preferably I would like to be able to express the distribution of r as a new normal distribution, which I think it is?

Comment: When you say "circular bivariate normal" do you mean independent (as well as equal standard deviation)?

Comment: That is what I mean :)

Comment: But r is obviously not normal. Its nonnegative. You should be able to identify the distribution of r^2 by inspection (failing that, let V=r^2 and it should become clear). The distribution of r is a standard distribution as well, though perhaps less familiar to you. You should show what answer you got.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $\sigma=1$, so you have two independent standard normal random variables, the the distribution of the radius squared is chi-squared with two degrees of freedom. For general $\sigma$ you have to scale that distribution.

That should give you your answer.